# Show that $p(A)\vec{v}=p(\lambda)\vec{v}$ when $A\vec{v}=\lambda\vec{v}$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Suppose $p(x)=c_0+c_1x+...+c_kx^k$. Let $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, $\vec{v}\in \mathbb{R}^n$, $A_{n\times n}$, such that $A\vec{v}=\lambda\vec{v}$. Show that for any $p(x)$, $p(A)\vec{v}=p(\lambda)\vec{v}$.

It seems to me that $A\vec{v}=\lambda\vec{v}\Rightarrow A=\lambda$, so that the problem is trivially proven. Is this correct reasoning?

Comment: $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix and $\lambda$ is a number. They can't be equal unless $n=1$.

Comment: Note that 
$$
\pmatrix{2&0\\0&0} \pmatrix{1\\0} = 2\pmatrix{1\\0}
$$
By your logic, this implies
$$
\pmatrix{2&0\\0&0} = 2
$$
So no: your reasoning is **not** correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is sufficient to prove that for all positive integers $p$,
$$A^pv=\lambda^pv$$
This holds by choice of $A$ and $\lambda$ if $p=1$. Otherwise, assume it holds for $p-1$. Then
$$A^pv=A(A^{p-1}v)=A\lambda^{p-1}v=\lambda^{p-1}(Av)=\lambda^pv$$
and the result follows by induction.

Answer (score 1):

It is not correct to say that

$A \vec v = \lambda \vec v \tag{1}$

for *some* $\vec v \ne 0$ implies

$A = \lambda I \tag{2}$

unless (1) holds for *every* $\vec v \in \Bbb R^n$.  A simple counterexample may be had by considering the $2 \times 2$ matrix $C$ given by

$C = \begin{bmatrix} \lambda_1 & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda_2 \end {bmatrix}, \tag{3}$

where

$\lambda_1 \ne \lambda_2; \tag{4}$

set

$\vec v_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, \; \;  \vec v_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}; \tag{5}$

then

$C \vec v_1 = \lambda_1 \vec v_1, \tag{6}$

$C \vec v_2 = \lambda_2 \vec v_2; \tag{7}$

but this contradicts (2), since (2) implies (1) holds for all vectors $\vec v$, including $\vec v_1$ and $\vec v_2$.  In more detail:  if (1) implied (2), then by (6) we would have

$C \vec v_2 = \lambda_1 \vec v_2; \tag{8}$

but then by (7),

$\lambda_1 \vec v_2 = \lambda_2 \vec v_2, \tag{9}$

whence

$(\lambda_1 - \lambda_2) \vec v_2 = 0, \tag{10}$

forcing

$\vec v_2 = 0, \tag{11}$

contradicting the definition of $\vec v_2$ in (5).  (1) may hold for *some* vectors without holding for *all*.

As for showing that (1) implies

$p(A) \vec v = p(\lambda) \vec v, \tag{12}$

for $p(x) = \sum_0^k c_i x^i$,

we observe that

$A^2 \vec v = A(A \vec v) = A(\lambda \vec v) = \lambda A \vec v = \lambda^2 \vec v; \tag{13}$

furthermore if

$A^m \vec v = \lambda^m \vec v, \tag{14}$

then

$A^{m + 1} \vec v = A^m A \vec v = A^m (\lambda \vec v) = \lambda A^m \vec v = \lambda^{m + 1} \vec v; \tag{15}$

with (1) and (2) forming the base hypotheses, (14)-(15) completes a simple inductive proof that

$A^i \vec v = \lambda^i \vec v \tag{16}$

holds for all integers $i \ge 0$ (the $i = 0$ case being the identity $\vec v = \vec v$).  Thus

$c_iA^i \vec v = c_i \lambda^i \vec v, \tag{17}$

whence

$p(A) \vec v = \sum_0^k c_i A^i \vec v = \sum_0^k c_i \lambda^i \vec v = p(\lambda) \vec v. \tag{18}$

***QED.***

Hope this helps.  Cheers,

and as ever,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Answer (score 0):

$A v = \lambda v$ for some $v$ need not imply $A = \lambda I,$ take $A$ to be the zero matrix   $, \lambda = 1$ and $v$ any vector with two components.

what you need to show is $A^2v = \lambda v, A^3 = \lambda^3 v, \cdots$

to show the above string of equalities take $A v = \lambda v$ and multiply by $A$ on the left.

Comment: Your first paragraph is a mystery; this is the one non-example to avoid. (Also what is two components? We are in $\Bbb R^n$.)

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen, i will put in the quantifier.

Answer (score 0):

A \vec{v} = \lambda \vec {v} doesnot imply A= \lambda.For example,

\pmatrix{2&0\0&2} \pmatrix{1\0} = 2\pmatrix{1\0}

but,
                \pmatrix{2&0\0&2} \ne 2.

Given,p(x)=c_0+c_1x+...+c_kx^k
which implies, p(A)=c_0+c_1A+...+c_kA^k

p(A)\vec v=c_0A\vec v+c_1A\vec v+...+c_kA^k\vec v \tag{1}

A \vec v = \lambda \vec v

implies  A^2 \vec v = A(A \vec v) = A(\lambda \vec v) = \lambda A \vec v = \lambda^2 \vec v

By induction,it follows that

A^m \vec v = \lambda^m \vec v \tag{2}

From \tag{1},and \tag{2}, it follows that

A)\vec{v}=p(\lambda)\vec{v}
Hope u understand!